# please help me convert this query to laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

SELECT SUM(  `srvce_volume` ) 
FROM work_order
WHERE DATE(  `updated_at` ) >=  '2018-01-18'
AND DATE(  `updated_at` ) <=  '2018-01-18'

Answer (score 1):

Start learning the query builder from [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries).

You need to use the `whereDate()` and `sum()` methods like this:

```
DB::table('work_order')->whereDate('updated_at', '2018-01-18')->sum('srvce_volume');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this, it is way too simple:

```
WorkOrder::where('updated_at', '>=', '2018-01-18')
         ->where('updated_at', '<=', '2018-01-18')
         ->get()
         ->sum('srvce_volume');
```

`WorkOrder` is simply your model.

Hope this helps you out.